# Android - Set Canvas to always be 1920x1080p?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, canvas, scaling

Im developing a mobile game in Java on a canvas. But when I use different sized phones, the alignments are wrong and the hard coded offset values to correctly place buildings don't match with the new canvas proportions. Also, the UI elements are wrong size now and dont match the screenheight. Feeling kind of lost on how to best solve this issue.

I know that hard-coding the game to always be 1080x1920p will probably lead to black bars on some phones, something I'd also want to avoid if possible.
Canvas.scale did not do the trick, it only achieved crashes.

Anybody got experience in this? Thanks!

Comment: Any code? How can we help you if all what we know is based only on your description?

Comment: I can show you how I set up my canvas but I felt like there might have been some general tips that didn't require code
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

c = view.getHolder().lockHardwareCanvas();
view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);

Here's an example of the values I had to spend a lot of time figuring out which I dont want to have to do again to match a new canvas size, since  on different phones they are out of alignment

 public int getOffSetX(String type) {
switch (type) {
case "wal0000":
return 43;

Comment: I see now that formating in comments isnt really possible. Whoops.I tried.

Comment: try adding code to question not in comment..

Comment: you can set canvas size using `Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(animation.getWidth(), animation.getHeight(), BITMAP_CONFIG);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);`